# Why doesn't php print this array value?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to display array values passed from my controller to the view however php is being selective over which values it prints.

The value I wish to output is     $cat['category_image'] however I get an Undefined index error when I access the page.

I'm using Codeigniter MVC and here's the code...

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $cat):?>          
        <li>

        <a href="<?=site_url('category/'.str_replace(" ", "-", strtolower($cat['category_name'])))?>">
            <div><?=$cat['category_name']?></div>

            <img src="<?=CDN_IMAGES . $cat['category_image']?>" width="210" height="315" border="0" />              
        </a>

        </li>           
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

If I do a print_r of the array value from the controller I get this...

```
Array
(
[catagories] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => 62
                [category_status] => SHOW
                [category_icon] => 
                [category_image] => cats\special.jpg
                [language_id] => en
                [category_name] => Specialties
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => 72
                [category_status] => SHOW
                [category_icon] => 
                [category_image] => cats\white.jpg
                [language_id] => en
                [category_name] => White wine 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => 82
                [category_status] => SHOW
                [category_icon] => 
                [category_image] => cats\rose.jpg
                [language_id] => en
                [category_name] => Rose
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => 92
                [category_status] => SHOW
                [category_icon] => 
                [category_image] => cats\red.jpg
                [language_id] => en
                [category_name] => Red Wine
            )

    )

)
```

Catagory name & id work fine however everything else throws the undefined error, can anyone help me with this? many thanks.

Comment: and `CDN_IMAGES` is certainly defined?

Comment: the print_r displays catagories and you are looping over categories, it is a typo?

Comment: I notice a misspelled `catagories` in your structure, although that is not likely to be the problem. Did you print this right before the foreach loop?

Comment: Have you tried accessing it outside of the loop? for instance, try accessing $categories[0]['category_image']

Comment: Spot on its a typo, silly me! Thanks all posters for having a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php foreach ($categories['catagories'] as $cat): ?>
```

^ pay attention to your `print_r` as the `$categories` array is actually `$categories['catagories']`.

**PS**: `['catagories']` ... `['categories']` ... weird. *Spell it right!*